# DLL lifetime and memoization

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, c++20, memoization

So I have bashed together a memoizing immutable pointer `memo_ptr<T>`

The interface is like this, so you know what I'm talking about

```
template<class T>
struct memo_ptr {
  // usual smart pointer methods.
  T const& operator*() const;
  T const* operator->() const;
  operator shared_ptr<const T>() const { return {m_pMemo, ptr}; }
  explicit operator bool() const;
  // blah blah blah

  T& write(); // copy on write accessor; if use count is 1, we recycle.

  // memoized conversion to another type
  // converting code run only if we don't already
  // have the alias stored
  template<class U>
  memo_ptr<U> convertTo( auto&& convertingCode ) const;
private:
  T* ptr = nullptr;
  std::shared_ptr< MemoizationCache > m_pMemo;
};
```

Use is like:

```
memo_ptr<Chicken> pChicken;
pChicken.write().eggs = 7;

memo_ptr<Blob> pBlob = serialize( pChicken );
assert( deserialize<Chicken>( pBlob ) == pChicken );
```

all fun and good.

My problem is this.  When you

```
pClicken.convertTo<Blob>( [&]{ /* serialization code, returns unique_ptr<Blob> */ } );
```

the Blob objects is created in the `Blob` dynamic library.

Now, if a `memo_ptr<Chicken>` with a `Blob` stored in it outlives the `Blob` dynamic library, when it is destroyed the code to cleanup the `Blob` is unloaded.  And boom, application crashes, trying to execute unloaded dynamic code.

As the design has a "anyone can add a memoized conversion" to an object design, this is a "an innocent mistake anywhere in the program can cause a crash at shutdown" problem.

On the other hand, once `Blob` dynamic library is unloaded, nobody should be asking for a `Blob` from a `memo_ptr<Chicken>` anymore; nor should anyone be holding a `memo_ptr<Blob>` while the `Blob` DLL is unloaded.  That is a different category of error; where someone is using `Blob`s after the dynamic library is unloaded.  The problem I have is that someone is holding a `Chicken` after `Blob` DLL is unloaded, and I'm caching a conversion-to-`Blob` secretly in it.

I had a similar problem for my earlier `immu_ptr`, where calls to `.write()` would store cleanup code in the resulting shared ptr coming from the location where `write()` was called.  I fixed this with an ADL helper function that converted unique ptrs to `Chicken` into shared ptr to `Chicken` whose lifetime began within `Chicken.dll`.

How should I solve this problem?  Note this is a cross-platform code base.  I use DLL as a short hand for dynamic library; a solution needs to work on mac, windows, linux, ios and android.  (As dynamic library loading isn't very cross-platform, implementation details may vary).

I don't want adding a new memoization type to require too much work on the part of the library that owns the type.  I don't want to have to anything fancy within the `convertTo` code someone writes.  I do want it to fail to build if we are risking a crash at shutdown.

---

Or, alternatively, I have some resource pointer.

```
resource_ptr<T>
```

and I want to guarantee that every instance of that resource is deleted before the DLL "owning" T is unloaded.  Nobody is going to read the smart resource pointer during, or after the DLL is unloaded, but the resource pointer could persist and be destroyed after the DLL is unloaded.

Comment: Could you handle the unload of DLL? I meant you might control "lifetime of DLL" with smart pointer too, and with alias `shared_ptr` constructors or capturing the `std::shared_ptr` handling the DLL for the memory coming from DLL, you won't unload DLL until last shared_ptr is alive.

Comment: @Jarod42 I can't have the DLL not be unloaded (or have it delayed) I don't think; we need predictable DLL unloading order for anything at all to stay sane.  Shutdown is hard, and smart-pointer-hell isn't going to "fix" it.

Comment: Dynamic library unloading may be causing troubles elsewhere and anywhere  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43121795/412080 For  that reason (which you may not be able to control) it may be best to disable dynamic library unloading.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin This is generally happening during application shutdown.  Are you proposing we should just exit(-1) instead of shutting down "cleanly"?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am saying that shared library unloading may cause totally unexpected problems when shared library dependent objects get stuck somewhere, like in the standard global stream objects. To avoid such problems one solution is to not unload the shared libraries. There may be better solutions depending on circumstances, but unloading a shared library doesn't have much benefit, does it?